# Extending Order Search Filter

Tags: magento2, orders, magento-1, collection

I got the task to port some custom build stuff from magento 1 to magento 2.
One function was the extension of the order api, now the OrderRepository.

In theory I got it running, but my problem is, that the filterGroups of the searchCriteria is empty.
We used the filterGroups as a container for some custom parameter to execute a SQL filter on the order collection.

e.g. as a parameter we use **invoiced_at** and adding an SQL to the collection where we collect all orders which invoice is created_at = invoiced_at

Is there any way to get and edit the filterGroups of the searchCriteria?

**di.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository">
        <plugin name="company_orderrepository_override"
            type="Company\SystemOverride\Model\Plugin\OrderRepositoryOverride" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>

</config>
```

**OrderRepositoryOverride.php**

```php
<?php
namespace Company\SystemOverride\Model\Plugin;

class OrderRepositoryOverride {

    protected $_request;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function aroundGetList(
            $subject,
            $proceed,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria) {
                $this->_logger->debug("_request: " . json_encode($this->_request));
                $this->_logger->debug("subject: " . json_encode(get_class_methods($subject)));
                $this->_logger->debug("proceed: " . json_encode(get_class_methods($proceed)));
                $this->_logger->debug("get_class_methods->searchCriteria: " . json_encode(get_class_methods($searchCriteria)));
                $this->_logger->debug("searchCriteria: " . json_encode($searchCriteria));
                $this->_logger->debug("getFilterGroups: " . json_encode($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups()));
                $this->_logger->debug("getSortOrders: " . json_encode($searchCriteria->getSortOrders()));
                $this->_logger->debug("getPageSize: " . json_encode($searchCriteria->getPageSize()));
                $this->_logger->debug("getCurrentPage: " . json_encode($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage()));
                $searchResult = $proceed($searchCriteria);
                return $searchResult;
    }
}
```

**debug.log**

```
main.DEBUG: _request: {} [] []
main.DEBUG: subject: ["__construct","get","getList","save","delete","deleteById","___init","___callParent","__sleep","__wakeup"] [] []
main.DEBUG: proceed: ["bind","bindTo","call","fromCallable"] [] []
main.DEBUG: get_class_methods->searchCriteria: ["getFilterGroups","getSortOrders","getPageSize","getCurrentPage","setFilterGroups","setSortOrders","setPageSize","setCurrentPage","__construct","setData","__toArray"] [] []
main.DEBUG: searchCriteria: {} [] []
main.DEBUG: getFilterGroups: [{}] [] []
main.DEBUG: getSortOrders: null [] []
main.DEBUG: getPageSize: 25 [] []
main.DEBUG: getCurrentPage: 0 [] []
```

**rest response**

```
{
  "items": [],
  "search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "created_at",
            "value": "2020-01-20",
            "condition_type": "eq"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "page_size": 25,
    "current_page": 0
  },
  "total_count": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :)

**print_r** helped a lot

```
main.DEBUG: Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria Object (
    [_data:protected] => Array (
        [filter_groups] => Array (
            [0] => Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup Object (
                [_data:protected] => Array (
                    [filters] => Array (
                        [0] => Magento\Framework\Api\Filter Object (
                            [_data:protected] => Array (
                                [field] => created_at
                                [value] => 2020-01-20
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        [page_size] => 25
        [current_page] => 0
    )
)
```

$searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() was an array containing an another array from $group->getFilters()

```
$this->_logger->debug(print_r($searchCriteria, true));
foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $group) {
    $this->_logger->debug(print_r($group, true));
    foreach ($group->getFilters() as $filter) {
      $this->_logger->debug(print_r($filter, true));
    }
}
```